# VLC succeeds in playing AMR files under Debian 12 but not under Mobian Bookworm

Tags: debian, vlc

I can play AMR files with VLC by using the codec named "samr" on my computer under Debian 12 but it doesn't work under Mobian on my Pinephone, I have no sound and I get the following error message:

```
main error: module not functional
main error: failed to create audio output
vlcpulse error: stream connection failure: incorrect state
```

I use VLC media player 3.0.18 Vetinari revision 3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2. I use Pipewire on both devices.

Does anybody have a clue?